# Dynamic URL generated by a custom field dropdown value

Tags: routing

I have a special case where the URL needs to be defined from within the entry itself. I have a dropdown that I want to populate with the URLs as values.

Can the dropdown value be used to generate the URL? I can not use custom site URLs because the customer/user needs to see the URL themselves from within the entry.

The entry is a channel.

So let's say the dropdown has a label called "Monkey". Then I want the URL to be /monkey/article-slug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the section settings, you can specify a dynamic [entry URI format](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#entry-uri-formats).

As the docs say, this box is in fact a mini Twig template, and is preloaded with the element being saved (accessible as `object`) and its custom fields (accessible directly by their handles). Good to know that you can also use a shortcut syntax with single braces instead of double ones here.

So in your case you'd want something like:

`{slugPrefixFieldHandle ? slugPrefixFieldHandle ~ '/' ~ slug : slug}`